# Android Robotium TestSuite

Tags: android, unit-testing, tdd, robotium

Is it possible for me to stop the Test from reinitializing (recalling the setUp function for each test)? I want the Test to setUp once, then it won't call the method again. Is it possible so that I can carry forward the result of the previous test to the next test.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's really bad idea. Tests no matter if they're instrumentation or unit should run independently from each other.

Declaration of `setup` run once make cause some incidental things, like you have a test which clicks on button and runs another activity. Next tests wants previous activity but they can't reach it so they fail.

I've already been writing `Espresso` tests using `JUnit4Runner` and I know that there's an annotation `@BeforeClass` which would be like `setup`, but it would run only once. If I would run some code before every test method I use `@Before` annotation, but like I said I think, that running `setUp` once is a bad idea and it hitting in the face an idea of instrumentation, more: automated UI testing.